# manipulation and using several substitution rule in indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

i'm need help to verifying my answer in

$$\int\frac{3x^2+3x}{x^3+3x} \, dx$$

this would be much simple if $3x$ in the numerator were $3$. but let's assume this question is valid and really mean to be like this.

i start with simplifying things

$$\int\frac{3x+3}{x^2+3} \, dx$$ then split the integral into

$$\int\frac{3x}{x^2+3} dx + \int\frac{3}{x^2+3}dx$$

then i make 2 kind of substitution rule :
let $u=x^2+3$ and $du=2x dx$ and use negative one power (natural logarithm) integration on left side and using inverse tangent subs and make right side of function above into

$\int\frac{1}{({x\sqrt{3}})^2+1}$ and after set things up and integrating i got

$$ 1.5 ln |x^2+3| + \frac {1}{\sqrt{3}} arctan (x\sqrt{3})  $$

Comment: Last integral should be $\int {1\over (x\color{red}{/}\sqrt 3)^2+1} dx$.

Comment: you can remove the absolute value since $x^2+3>0$ for each $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @DavidMitra oh thank you ! i missed that

Comment: @pikarin-g The second integral is $\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$, and don't forget the constant.